# Java preserving abstraction in class hierarchy while allowing for lower class interaction and multiple isolated upper class instantiations?

Tags: java, oop, abstraction, class-hierarchy

I want to have multiple isolated instances of a "commander" class (no static fields or methods) which brings together all the classes below it. The classes below should be ignorant of this "commander" class's existence in order to abstract implementation details.

In this first attempt, LowerClass1 has to access the CentralClass in order to interact with LowerClass2 (through an instance of LowerClass2). CentralClass should only be able to access the classes below itself, the classes below CentralClass should not be able to access it. This example shows LowerClass1 accessing the class above it (CentralClass) in order to reach another class on it's own level (LowerClass2).

```
public class CentralClass {
    public LowerClass1 lowerClass1;
    public LowerClass2 lowerClass2;
}

public class LowerClass1 {
    public void exampleMethod1() {
        CentralClass.lowerClass2.exampleMethod2();
    }
}

public class LowerClass2 {
    public void exampleMethod2() {
    
    }
}
```

Basically, LowerClass1 is being made aware of the existence of the "commander" class above it in order to access the instance of the LowerClass2 class on its own level.

In this next attempt, while LowerClass1 can access LowerClass2 without accessing CentralClass, CentralClass can no longer have isolated instances because of the static methods of LowerClass2. While the upwards flow of the class hierarchy is preserved, I can no longer create multiple isolated instances of CentralClass.

```
public class CentralClass {
    public LowerClass1 lowerClass1;
}

public class LowerClass1 {
    public void exampleMethod1() {
        LowerClass2.exampleMethod2();
    }
}

public class LowerClass2 {
    public static void exampleMethod2() {
    
    }
}
```

In both cases, either the flow was broken where a class ascended and descended multiple class levels (breaking hierarchy and introducing confusion), or the higher class level was unable to isolate multiple instances because of the static connections between lower classes.

How would I preserve the hidden abstraction of the lower classes to the upper classes while avoiding the use of static so the upper classes can have multiple isolated instances? Would using separate class loaders be an option? Are there any design patterns that might be helpful in this situation?

Comment: If my gobbledygook is too incoherent (I had a hard time expressing this idea), just read the code blocks and the part after the last code block for most of the context.

Comment: In your first example, `LowerClass1` does not have any reference to the `LowerClass2` instance, neither direct nor indirect, so this wouldn’t pass the compiler. If, on the other hand, you can easily convert `exampleMethod2()` into a `static` method like you did when going to the second example, there are other problems with your design.

Comment: If you just want LowerClass1 to have access to a LowerClass2 instance, either pass the LowerClass2 object as an argument to exampleMethod1, or pass a `Suppler<LowerClass2>` argument to exampleMethod1.  You also could pass that Supplier to the constructor of LowerClass1.

Comment: @VGR While that does give my lower classes access, it is very unintuitive. A direct reference to the class through LowerClass2.exampleMethod2() is much less confusing than a call to an instance of that class such as CentralClass.lowerClass2.exampleMethod2().

Comment: I don’t share your opinion.  I don’t think static methods for everything is intuitive at all.  If I have a class called Vehicle with a method `openTrunk()`, it would be very strange for openTrunk() to be a static method.  Which vehicle’s trunk am I opening?  Every vehicle in the parking lot?

Comment: After your change, the first example still is invalid. You’re trying to access the instance field `lowerClass2` is if it was `static`. This seems to be a general problem; you seem to think that whether members are `static` or not is not important. Besides that, since `LowerClass1` is invoking a method of `LowerClass2` in either case, there is no “isolation” anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that isolates the classes while preserving their hierarchy.

```
public class CentralClass {
    public LowerClass1 lowerClass1 = new LowerClass1(new LowerClass2());
}

public class LowerClass1 {
    private LowerClass2 lowerClass2;
    
    public LowerClass1(LowerClass2 lowerClass2) {
        this.lowerClass2 = lowerClass2;
    }
    
    public void exampleMethod1() {
        this.lowerClass2.exampleMethod2();
    }
}

public class LowerClass2 {
    public void exampleMethod2() {
    
    }
}
```